# Ubuntu server (VM) hangs after "Begin: Running /scripts/init-bottom ... done"

Tags: boot, init

My bootup hangs, as seen in the image below. (**there has been an update. check the edit below**)

[image]

When I press escape, it tabs to this screen :

[image]

### The whole story :

This VM ubuntu server is used for a website. The website suddenly had an error, and I thought turning it off and turning it on would fix it. (heh)

**Never had I been more wrong.**

So I ran `sudo /sbin/reboot` which I do sometimes and it normally works afterwards. But this time, it doesn't.

I tried accessing the VM console, rebooted it from there, and now the bootup hangs at the shown image above.

Help?

---

Additional details :

- Ubuntu linux 3.0.0-32-server
- We're using vSphere client for the VM
- As you can see, I'm not exactly the Linux expert

---

### Edit

I removed the fsck checks but it still hangs. I pressed `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to see the text logs and this is the result.

[image]

Comment: For what it's worth, ubuntu 11.10 is now [end of life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)... while not a solution to your issue, this might be a good time to consider upgrading to 12.04 or 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Check file owner and permissions of the init script on the root filesystem:

```
# ls -l /sbin/init
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 167192 Jan 18  2013 /sbin/init
```